# Excel 2003: Calendar Object / VBA won't work when clicking merged cells

Tags: vba, excel, merge, calendar

I'm having a little issue getting the calendar object I've inserted into my excel sheet to work. I have an identical calendar object, with identical (except for the column reference) code on another sheet that works perfectly. The only difference is that in Sheet A (the problem sheet) the cells I'm selecting (where I want the calendar object to pop up) are merged and centered. This seems to cause an issue. When I set the reference in the code to be the entire of column L for  example, the calendar object will work for all cells in that column that have not been merged or centered. (To be clear, the cells are only merged in the column and not across any rows). Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this? I have to have those cells merged, there isn't anyway I can get round that. If anyone has any suggestions I'd really appreciate it, this has been driving me nuts all day! Thank you in advance.

Code (not my own) is below;

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
      'Change this to your range of dates
     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L:L")) Is Nothing Then
       Calendar2.Top = Target.Top + Target.Height
       Calendar2.Left = Target.Left + Target.Width / 2 - Calendar2.Width / 2
       Calendar2.Visible = True
       Calendar2.Value = Now
     ElseIf Calendar2.Visible Then Calendar2.Visible = False
    End If
 End Sub
 Private Sub Calendar2_Click()
 ActiveCell.Value = (Calendar2.Value)
 ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "dd mmm yy"
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select a merged cell's range, then `Target.Cells.Count` is always greater than 1. There are more than one cell, even if you can't select them individually.

If you need only allow select single cells or single merged ranges, then you could do:

```
If Target.Address <> Target.Cells(1, 1).MergeArea.Address Then Exit Sub
```

This will work with single cells and with merged cells.

Comment: Axel, thank you very much indeed for that perfect answer. That's got the it working 100% now, appreciate the quick response! Have a great day, mine certainly is better now. Thanks again!